# Using a List type in Template Meta Programming

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I have an encoding scheme where I convert a the digits [0-9] using the following rule:

> 0 - 3
>   1 - 7
>   2 - 2
>   3 - 4
>   4 - 1
>   5 - 8
>   6 - 9
>   7 - 0
>   8 - 5
>   9 - 6

I can therefore use the following array to do the forward lookup
`int forward[] = { 3,7,2,4,1,8,9,0,5,6}`
where `forward[n]` is the encoding for n.
similarly the following for the inverse lookup
`int inverse{ 7,4,2,0,3,8,9,1,5,6};`
where `inverse[n] will decode n

the inverse array can easily be created from the forward array at runtime but ideally, I would like to create it at compile time. Given that template metaprogramming is a functional language, I implemented everything in Haskell first using:

```
pos :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
pos lst x = 
    let 
        pos'::[Int] -> Int -> Int -> Int
        pos' (l:lst) x acc
            | l == x = acc
            | lst == [] = -1
            | otherwise = pos' lst x (acc + 1)
    in
        pos' lst x 0

inverse ::[Int] -> [Int]
inverse lst =
    let
        inverse'::[Int] -> Int -> [Int]
        inverse' l c 
            | c == 10 = []
            | otherwise = pos l c : inverse' l (c + 1)
    in
        inverse' lst 0
```

I managed to implement `pos` in C++ template meta-programming using:

```
#include <iostream>

static int nums[] = {3,7,2,4,1,8,9,0,5,6};

template <int...>
struct pos_;

template <int Find, int N, int Arr0, int... Arr>
struct pos_<Find,N, Arr0, Arr...> {
    static constexpr int value = pos_<Find, N+1, Arr...>::value;
};

template <int Find, int N, int... Arr>
struct pos_<Find ,N, Find, Arr...> {
    static constexpr int value = N;
};

template <int Find,int N>
struct pos_<Find ,N> {
    static constexpr int value = -1;
};

template <int Find, int... Arr>
struct pos {
    static constexpr int value = pos_<Find,0, Arr...>::value;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "the positions are ";

    std::cout << pos<3, 3,7,2,4,1,8,9,0,5,6>::value << std::endl;
}
```

However I am having trouble converting an array into a parameter pack and when it comes to implementing inverse, I cannot assign `value` to a parameter pack.

What is the best way to approach the use of lists in template meta-programming?

For context, this problem came to mind when looking at Base64 encoding and I was wondering if there was a way to compile-time generate the reverse encoding.

Comment: I think it can be done using mostly `constexpr` and not a lot of TMP. Do you want to use TMP specifically?

Comment: This for me is a learning experience, and I am not familiar with the use of constexpr for algorithms so yes. (although I would like to know the meta-programming solution as well.

Comment: why store your numbers in array and not in as a type in `pos<...>` ?

Comment: the array/template parameter pack conversion is a big problem, IMHO; if you can use C++17, I suggest to use metaprogramming based over `std::array` (starting from C++17, `operator[]` is `constexpr`) and `constexpr` functions; see the Dean M.'s answer for an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest/cleanest way to produce inverse array at compile-time is by writing `constexpr` inverse function. Along the lines of:

```
template<size_t N>
constexpr std::array<int, N> inverse(const std::array<int, N> &a) {
    std::array<int, N> inv{};
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        inv[a[i]] = i;
    }
    return inv;
}
```

you can see it in action here: https://godbolt.org/g/uECeie

If you want something closer to your initial approach/Haskell, you can just look up on how to implement compile-time lists using TMP and how to write familiar functions for them (like append and concat). After that implementing inverse would become trivial. Btw, ignoring the general C++ syntax clankiness, those definitions would be very similar in spirit to what you would find in functional languages.

Comment: +1; but, IMHO, you should signal that this function can works `constexpr` only starting from C++17 (the modifying `operator[]` isn't `constexpr` before).

Comment: @max66 good point. You could workaround it by using a helper function that would find the inverse for given index. Something like: https://godbolt.org/g/V7to4N (uses only C++14, can be modified further to only use C++11 with much more code).

Comment: Yes: this workaround can work starting from C++14; for C++11 you have to add a substitute for `std::index_sequence`/`std::make_index_sequence` and make `find()` recursive.